# Getting run-time error 1004 while trying to calculate using formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a run-time error while trying to calculate a common excel formula in VBA.
Here's the part of the code that seems to have problems:

```
   With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   .Range("F4").Formula = "=IF(AND(C5=0;D5=0;E5=0);B5;IF(AND(C5=0;OR(D5<>0;E5<>0));B5;0))"
   .Range("F4").Copy
    With .Range("F5:F" & LastRow)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With
End With
```

I'think there's simply something wrong in writing the formula using the correct VBA syntax, since if i just substitute with "=2+2" it works.

Comment: Please try to change semicolon(;) to comma(,). And try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Semicolon` with `Comma`

```
"=IF(AND(C5=0,D5=0,E5=0),B5,IF(AND(C5=0,OR(D5<>0,E5<>0)),B5,0))"
```